# Screenshot prevention for another application

Tags: android, screenshot, screen-recording

Is it possible to develop an Android app that prevents screenshots or screen recording of another app?

For example, a video is streaming on some video player and I want to develop a app that prevent recording of that streaming.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible, that's up to an app if they made it secure enough to not let the phone take a screenshot. You have control over your app only and can't control any other app which is not developed by you.